# purpose of roslaunch_add_file_check()?

Tags: husky, cmake, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After working through most of the ROS tutorials, I have started studying some of the code for the robots listed on the wiki.  I am trying to become a "fluent" ROS developer.  To that end, I am trying to figure out what "roslaunch_add_file_check(launch)" does in this CMakeLists.txt file: https://github.com/husky/husky_simulator/blob/indigo-devel/husky_gazebo/CMakeLists.txt.  (Google seems to indicate that roslaunch_add_file_check() is related to testing, but that package does not have any tests.)  What does that line do, and what is its purpose?

Also, is there a general way to find out about ROS-specific CMake functions like that one?  I am sure I will have other questions like this in the future.  Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200359/purpose-of-roslaunch_add_file_check()?/) by [Sam Bishop](https://answers.ros.org/users/21272/sam-bishop/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2015-01-03

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unfortunately this was never documented, but the documentation for `rosbuild_add_roslaunch_check` is close:

http://wiki.ros.org/rosbuild/CMakeLists#rosbuild_add_roslaunch_check

The function you are inquiring about is the "rosbuild-less" equivalent function and in the case you are asking about it is operating on the entire `launch` folder, which I presume contains one or more `.launch` files. Even the `rosbuild` version's documentation does not clearly state what exactly it checks:

> This macro declares as a unit test a parse check of one or more roslaunch files. The parser (roslaunch/scripts/roslaunch-check) checks a number of aspects of launch files, in a manner similar to roswtf.

Another thing to do is to look at the script it seems to invoke for the test:

https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/1.11.10/tools/roslaunch/scripts/roslaunch-check

There should probably be something about that script documented here:

http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Commandline%20Tools

And some mention of the CMake commands provided by `roslaunch` here:

http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch#Overview

It seems the reason that documentation doesn't exist in those places is that the function used to be provided by `rosbuild` but is now provided by `roslaunch` and that never got documented and at the same time the CMake function was added where `roslaunch` previously had no documented CMake API either.

Adding this to the wiki would be a great contribution, assuming you have the time and figure out more about what the check actually checks.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sam Bishop](https://answers.ros.org/users/21272/sam-bishop/) on 2015-01-04**:
Thank you very much!  I will certainly look at modifying the wiki.

**Comment by [Sam Bishop](https://answers.ros.org/users/21272/sam-bishop/) on 2015-01-12**:
I've modified the wiki, but only the main roslaunch page. There are a few things about roslaunch-check that makes me think it wasn't intended to be used directly, so I didn't add it to the tools page. (It's not added to PATH, for instance.) You're welcome to make further changes. And thanks again!

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-01-12**:
Looks fine to me, thanks for your help!